# LDAP PHP last logon timestamp

Tags: php, ldap, timestamp

i have this code that can get the tag of a computer, the operting system and the lastlogon timestamp.

The problem is that i cant get the timestamp code to be displayed so humans can understand it.

Is there a way to implement this in this code?

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

$host = "ldap://server.server.net";
$user = "domain\user";
$pswd = "passw";

$ad = ldap_connect($host)
      or die( "Could not connect!" );


ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
     or die ("Could not set ldap protocol");

// Binding to ldap server
$bd = ldap_bind($ad, $user, $pswd)
      or die ("Could not bind");

// Create the DN
$dn = "OU=NotebookM2,OU=WorkstationsM2,OU=PT1,DC=heiway,DC=net";



$attrs = array("cn","operatingsystem","lastlogon");

// Create the filter from the search parameters
$filter = $_POST['filter']."=".$_POST['keyword']."*";

$search = ldap_search($ad, $dn, $filter, $attrs)
          or die ("ldap search failed");

$entries = ldap_get_entries($ad, $search);

if ($entries["count"] > 0) {
  echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>";
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>TAG:</td>";
  echo "<td>OS:</td>";
  echo "<td>Last Logon:</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

for ($i=0; $i<$entries["count"]; $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$entries[$i]["cn"][0]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$entries[$i]["operatingsystem"][0]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0]."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";

} else {
   echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1","<p>Ops Nothing Found</p>");
}

ldap_unbind($ad);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this
add this function

```
function ldapTimeToUnixTime($ldapTime) {
    $unixTime = 0;
    /* LDAP time is assumed to start with "YYYYMMDDhhmmss" and to be in a 
     * Greenwith Meantime format.
     */
    $pat = '/^([0-9]{4,4})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})' .
    '([0-9]{2,2}).*/';

    if(preg_match($pat, $ldapTime, $matches) > 0) {
            $unixTime = gmmktime($matches[4], $matches[5], $matches[6],
              $matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1]);
    }
    return $unixTime;
}
```

replace the line

```
echo "<td>".$entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0]."</td>";
```

with

```
$timestamp=ldapTimeToUnixTime($entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0]);
echo "<td>". gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp) ."</td>";
```

Comment: Working but i get:
'
2020-06-10T02:17:36Z 
'
and is i change the code to 

$timestamp=$entries[$i]["lastlogon"][0];
echo "<td>". gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s ", $timestamp) ."</td>"; 

i get 

10-06-2020 02:17:36 

2020???

Comment: gmdate is for converting from unix timestamp whats your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, even if i change from gmdate to date, i still get strange dates like 1987 or 1970 etc.

Comment: I already found an answer: Very slick code: http://www.mdloring.com/2013/php-convert-activedirectory-timestamp-ldap-php/